Why does 'git rebase --strategy-option=theirs master' still conflict?
If I run:
git rebase --strategy-option=theirs master

I expect it to rebase my branch onto master, and resolve any conflicts using my branch.
However I get:
Auto-merging versions.bzl
error: could not apply 43b0d2f4e47... Did something
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 43b0d2f4e47... Did something

Why is the rebase aborting with conflicts, even though I've specified the --strategy-option?

Have you looked at the specific conflict? -X theirs doesn't work for all possible conflict types (f/e, it doesn't make sense when you've got ambiguous file renames)

@CharlesDuffy That sounds like a completely valid answer to me :-)

@TimBiegeleisen, ...it would be if the question had a [mre] or otherwise enough information to confirm it; right now, it's just speculation on a question that's unanswerably incomplete.

Afraid it's far too complex a repo to try and extract out examples of all the changes that have been made to this point.  The docs don't mention anything about "types" of conflict.
Is there a list anywhere of all the "possible conflict types" -X theirs doesn't work for?
I want all conflicts to be resolved with the version that is on the branch.

-X theirs is not a magic bullet: in a merge/rebase context, it does not always cleanly overwrite every single conflict type.
Git will still stop on more intricate or ambiguous conflicts. E.g., file renames, or other scenarios that simply cannot be auto-resolved by a blind "take their content" approach: If files have been renamed or moved differently in both branches, Git might need user guidance.
So do check your Git version:

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), a new default merge strategy is in place:  ORT ("Ostensibly Recursive's Twin"), with clearer conflict messages (Git 2.36, Q2 2022)

you can preview those conflicts with (Git 2.38, Q3 2022):
git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages branch1 branch2

(That would not touch the index or working tree!)


